# How can I delete Internet Explorer cookies using bat script?

Tags: batch-file, cookies, windows-7, command, internet-explorer-11

I have written a simple bat script for my computer to do a few things. One of these things is to delete cookies from my computer.

I chose the following command to do this;

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
```

since the following list of commands was given on this page;

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ce81943b-32b8-437b-b620-171c3d5893e7/inetcplcpl-with-clearmytracksbyprocess?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

```
echo Clear Temporary Internet Files: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8 


echo Clear Cookies: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 


echo Clear History: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1 


echo Clear Form Data: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16 


echo Clear Saved Passwords: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32 


echo Delete All: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255 


echo Delete All w/Clear Add-ons Settings: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
```

However, running my antivirus software after running this still deletes lots of cookies, so I know that it isn't deleting cookies as expected. It does however, clear my internet history.

Is anyone able to explain why this isn't working? Have Microsoft changed IE so that cookies cannot be deleted, or are websites using a different folder for cookies? Also, what command should I be using to successfully delete cookies?

Comment: you run your script with normal permissions, while IE runs at low IL (caused by UAC) this is why the cookies are still there

Comment: what does IL refer to here?

Comment: IL =  Integrity levels: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx

Comment: do I just change my UAC settings to fix this?

Comment: run it at low IL with **psexec -l **

Comment: protected mode is Medium integrity  level not the low Integrity . Internet Explorer cash in both of them protected (Medium Integrity) level and the none protected (Low Integrity) Level.when you delete you delete only Low Integrity level container of cash.but Medium still there holding protected cash.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, rundll32.exe when you run it normally, it runs under Medium IL. There is a way to launch it in low IL so that it can wipe out stuff in IE temporary internet files\Low folder. Simply make a copy of rundll32.exe and set it to run in Low IL using CACLS. More here: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/rundll32-command-clear-ie-cache-ineffective-windows-vista-higher/

It's amazing most people simply believe that the cache is cleared by running the command normally.

Comment: I'd prefer the PSEXEC variant because RUNDLL might be updated occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this batch file is not using command line to run `Rundll32.exe` because command line can't execute this lines but vbscript can so Turn around batch to use VBScript but in batch command
mean create VBscript file with command line and the run this vbscript file then delete

```
@echo off
(
echo  with createobject^("wscript.shell"^)
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8" 
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2" 
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1"
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16" 
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32" 
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255" 
echo .exec "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351"
echo End with
) > %tmp%\r.vbs && start /wait %tmp%\r.vbs && del /f %tmp%\r.vbs
```

Comment: hey @hollopost,
Is this specific for IE or it works with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
copy %windir%\system32\RUNDLL32.EXE %TMP%\RUNDLL32-IL.EXE
ICACLS %TMP%\RUNDLL32-IL.EXE /SETINTEGRITYLEVEL LOW
echo createobject^("shell.application"^).shellexecute "cmd.exe",""" /c START /W /B %TMP%\RunDll32-IL.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255""","","runas",0  > %TMP%\rundll32.vbs
start /w /b %TMP%\rundll32.vbs
```

First make copy from **`Rundll32.exe`**  in `Temp` Folder
Then change the Integrity level for that copy to low so no protection mode when it run
Then Run it as administrator to clean the internet exeplorer